# SignalR Hub Sending signal to Specific client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr-hub

I am trying to send an alert message to other users that currently on the same URL as the updater.

Let say I am on page `.../Customers/Detail/597` and update it.

As soon as the page reloads, I want to send a signal to the users that are currently on the same page `(.../Customers/Detail/597)`

Currently, even if the other users are on a different page like `.../Customers/Detail/687` they still get the alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using something like

In your asp.net mvc side (from where you are sending the message)

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.NotifyUser(id, message);
```

and in your javascript (where you are accepting)

```
//you must have that Id (from URL) in your javascript too so you can check if user is currently on that spage
var id = ...; 
hub.client.NotifyUser = function(serverId, message) {

    if(id == serverId)
    {
        //do something with the message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a group(s), with the ID of the page as the name.  You can then message only the group associated with the page ID.

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#groupsfromhub